# how to get last day of a month using command prompt

Tags: cmd

I wanted to get the last day of any month which is passed using the command prompt. Can someone from you help me with the same.

There should be a command which should contain a number like 4 which stands for April and the output should contain 30.

Answer (score 0):

You could use some vbscript.

```
if WScript.Arguments(0) = "12" Then
NextMonth=1
Else
NextMonth=WScript.Arguments(0) + 1
End If

wscript.echo(Split(DateAdd("d", -1, DateSerial(year(now), NextMonth, 1)), "/", 3, 1)(1))
```

Just save this into something like GetLastDay.vbs, and run it like this:

```
cscript /nologo GetLastDay.vbs (month number)
```

...where (month number) is a number from 1 to 12. Note that there is no error checking, so make sure you pass in something valid. It also assumes the current year, so if you pass in 2, you'll get 29 because this is a leap year. Next year you would get 28.

What this script does is take your month and create a date object for the first day of the month AFTER the month you supplied, and then subtract one day to land on the last day of the month BEFORE (which is the month you requested). It then uses Split() to get the day token out of the resulting date string.

Comment: @Anoop, if this answers your question, please help me out and mark it as the answer. I'm trying to earn points. Looking back at your past questions, it doesn't look like you've done for any of the answers you've gotten. Maybe go and do that for others who have helped you out too. :)